# Method for multi-label category classification

Tags: nlp, multilabel-classification

I’m working on a project that involves a Natural Language Processing methodology. I want to classify categories(label) to biomedical news articles (it can be multi-label)
(For example, News 1: Oncology, News 2: Cardiology, Neurology)

I think I can retrieve enough new articles. The number of labels would be around 50.
Before assigning labels, I need to decide the method.

I guess there would be two options: 'Multi-label text classification' and 'NER'.

Below are my considerations for category classifcation.

- specific jargons are most important for classifying categories.
- text classification will assess every word of each news article.
- sequence of words and contextualization may be less important than other tasks (topic classification, sentiment analysis, etc.).
- I have once experienced sort of classification task but new to NER. Unlke text classification, NER does not output the final result(category). NER would classify biomedical terms and I think I need to do something using these terms.

Which method will be more beneficial? Or is there any better method?
Thanks in advance!